# Install VS Code Packages to work in Multiple Conda Environments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have several Python projects using different environments. These environments are managed using Conda and this works well, allowing the same environment to be used in production and dev/test for each project.

Conda yml files are used to define each environment.

There are a number of packages that I would like to use during development, such as autopep8. These don't need to be in the production environment so are not included in the yml file.

How can I install autopep8 and others so that they will work across any Python environment that I load in VS Code? So far I have had to manually install these packages as I switch environments.

Comment: In VS Code, the installed python module is stored in "\Lib\site-packages" of the currently used python environment by default. Therefore, this module can be recognized only if the required module is installed in the currently used python environment. Reference: [Python environments in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: Have you looked into [setting default packages](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#adding-default-packages-to-new-environments-automatically)? The `conda env create` command will respect them, and whenever you have an env that doesn’t need it you can use a `--no-default-packages` flag. You could set this in the `.condarc` on only your dev systems.

Comment: Great suggestion @merv - I haven't look at them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Default Packages

One way of managing this without violating environment isolation<sup>**1**</sup> would be to use [Conda's default packages functionality](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#adding-default-packages-to-new-environments-automatically). The idea would be to define default packages (such as `autopep8`) in a `.condarc` on only the development systems. The `conda env create` will respect these and add them to every env you create, so you can still keep a single YAML that describes only the essentials for the production version.

Note that [there are multiple options](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#searching-for-condarc) for where to store this `.condarc`, and Conda can load settings in a nested fashion. If all environments for your user are categorized as "development", then a sensible place to define the default packages would be `~/.condarc`. There is additionally a `--no-default-packages` flag, which can be used to disable such default package installation when you don't need it.

---

<sub>**[1]** While there are ways to include packages from outside a Conda environment (e.g., through `PYTHONPATH`), this should be regarded as substandard and only be used as a last resort. Conda is designed with an assumption of full isolation of environments - violating that can lead to undefined behavior.</sub>